# Disabling a row in table depending on the web page you are in

Tags: asp.net, master-pages

I have a table as side bar in the master page which is coded as follows in webstore.master

```
 <div class="Sidebar" runat="server">
        <table width="140px" border="0" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td class="LeftButton">
                        <a class="LeftButton" href="Home.aspx">Continue Shopping</a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
            <tr>
                <td class="LeftButton">
                    <a class="LeftButton" href="ShoppingCart.aspx">Edit Shopping Cart</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="LeftButton">
                    <a class="LeftButton" href="CheckOut.aspx">Check Out</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="LeftButton">
                    <a class="LeftButton" href="MySoftware.aspx">My Software</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
```

I inherit this onto every other content page in the project. But now i want to disable a specific row depending upon the page i'm in.

For example if i'm in home.aspx i want to disable the row titled "Continue Shopping".
similary if i'm in Checkout.aspx i want to disable the row titled "Check out"

How can i achieve this.

BTW i'm using VS 2008, asp.net/c#

Thanks in anticipation

Comment: Do you have to do it like this? I think that creating a user control with properties would be better and easier to configure at each page. If you want to do it on server (so not on client with javascript).

Comment: It's in the master page. So it is a one time code only, and JavaScript is not in the question anyway;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the simple solution:

```
<div class="Sidebar" runat="server">
        <table width="140px" border="0" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2">
            <%if(!Request.Url.ToString().Contains("home.aspx")){%>
              <tbody>   
                <tr>
                    <td class="LeftButton">
                        <a class="LeftButton" href="Home.aspx">Continue Shopping</a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
            <%}%>
            <tr>
                <td class="LeftButton">
                    <a class="LeftButton" href="ShoppingCart.aspx">Edit Shopping Cart</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
           <%if(!Request.Url.ToString().Contains("CheckOut.aspx")){%>
            <tr>
                <td class="LeftButton">
                    <a class="LeftButton" href="CheckOut.aspx">Check Out</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <%}%>
            <tr>
                <td class="LeftButton">
                    <a class="LeftButton" href="MySoftware.aspx">My Software</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
```

You get the idea.

Otherwise make a control that does the same thing in codebehind.
that would be a bit more elegant, but basicly the same. :-)